# R: Spectral clustering for text classification

Tags: r, classification, cluster-analysis, tm, kernlab

I am using the `tm` package to create a corpus of documents and I want to use spectral clustering (`kernlab` package) for text classification.

So, if I have a corpus

`my_corpus = VCorpus(DirSource(directory="C:/Users/me/Desktop/Documents", pattern="txt")`

And I want to perform spectral clustering using the `specc` function which takes the following arguments

`specc(x, centers, kernel)`

What do I put as the first argument? The documentation says that x has to be "the matrix of data to be clustered, or a symbolic description of the model to be fit, or a kernel Matrix of class kernelMatrix, or a list of character vectors". But simply putting `my_corpus` doesn't work. So I am confused how this works if you have a corpus of documents.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose an appropriate kernel
2. Compute kernel matrix
3. Spectral clustering
4. Evaluate, evaluate, evaluate. Clustering is likely to fail, but produce a result nevertheless. And on text, any result can be interpreted to look good... see the two publications on topic modeling with 'reading tea leaves" in the title!

Comment: My question is how to compute the kernel matrix if you have a corpus of documents. Do you know this?

Comment: Whichever way you want. That's straightforward. You need the K(i,j) for any two documents, store them in a matrix.

Comment: What do you mean with K(i,j) though? Is there a standard function to convert a matrix to a kernel matrix?

Comment: K is the kernel function you want to use.

Comment: first try to play with your document-term matrix by dtm <-
 DocumentTermMatrix(my_corpus)

Answer (score 0):

x requires a Matrix ir a Dataframe. A Corpus is not any if them. You should transform the Corpus into a document-term-matrix and them convert It to Matrix format.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide an example?